# PC/SC with PHP5 in windows with wampServer

Tags: php, wamp, pcsc

I'm trying to read public data from smartCard with wampServer, PHP 5.4, winSCard and php_pcsc.dll for PHP5 (http://pecl.php.net/package/pcsc/0.2/windows).

I found this project http://hanez.org/pcsc-for-php.html (code is for php4 but my dll is for php5) and tried to do in localhost but php throws me this error "Call to undefined function SCardListReaders()".

When I see de phpinfo I can see the extension enabled but it hasn't any information (I can't put images because I haven't points), only has table headers

```
      PC/SC
```

---

| PC/SC support  |  enabled |

---

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be getting an error because the function is actually `scard_list_readers()` not `SCardListReaders()` as the error shows in your post.

But before you can use most of the functions, you need to establish a context first.

Try:

```
$context = scard_establish_context();
$readers = scard_list_readers($context);

print_r($readers);

// then when you have your card reader's identity from $readers

$connection = scard_connect($context, 'YOUR CARD READER HERE');
$response   =  scard_transmit($connection, 'pdu string');
```

Comment: Thank you @drew010 for your help :)